# JavaScript Присвоение функции переменной

Tags: javascript

При присвоении функции переменной, в переменной хранится тело функции или результат ее вызова?

Например:

```js
function addN(n) {
  let adder = function(x) {
    return n + x
  }
  return adder
}
let a = addN(2)
```

При вызове **`a`**, будет заново создаваться функция с подставлением аргумента вместо **`n`** или в **`a`** уже хранится `adder` со значением `n=2`?

Answer (score 4):

```js
function addN(n) {
  let adder = function(x) { // (*1)
    return n + x;
  }
  return adder;
} 

let a = addN(2);

console.log( a(3) );
```

Как и все другие переменные-имена функций. Хранят не прямо объект функции, а адрес этой функции в памяти.

При вызове `addN(2)` создается функция `(*1)`, и через `return adder;` ссылка на эту функцию попадает в переменную `a`. Каждый раз, когда вызывают `a()` — не создается новая функция, а вызывается ранее созданная `(*1)`, которая начинает искать ближайшую переменную с названием `n` и находит её в своем окружении (параметр `addN(n)`)

Answer (score 1):

Сколько нужно времени, чтобы это выяснить?

```js
function addN(n) {
  let adder = function(x) {
    return n + x
  }
  return adder
}
let a = addN(2)

console.log(a);
console.log(a(1),a(2),a(3));
```